# How to config spring-websocket with 'WebApplicationInitializer'

Tags: java, spring, spring-java-config, spring-websocket

**How to config spring-websocket with 'WebApplicationInitializer':**

**WebAppInitializer.java**

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)throws ServletException {

    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext SpringWebSocketContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    SpringWebSocketContext.register(WebSocketConfig.class);
}
```

}

**WebSocketConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@ComponentScan({ "service" })
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/hello").withSockJS();
    }

}
```

**GreetingController.java**

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {
    @MessageMapping("/hello")
    @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
    public Greeting greeting(HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(3000); // simulated delay
        return new Greeting("Hello, " + message.getName() + "!");
    }

}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello WebSocket</title>
    <script src="lib/sockjs/sockjs.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/sockjs/stomp.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var stompClient = null;

        function setConnected(connected) {
            document.getElementById('connect').disabled = connected;
            document.getElementById('disconnect').disabled = !connected;
            document.getElementById('conversationDiv').style.visibility = connected ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
            document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = '';
        }

        function connect() {
            var socket = new SockJS('/hello');
            stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
            stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
                setConnected(true);
                console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
                stompClient.subscribe('/topic/greetings', function(greeting){
                    showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
                });
            });
        }

        function disconnect() {
            stompClient.disconnect();
            setConnected(false);
            console.log("Disconnected");
        }

        function sendName() {
            var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
            stompClient.send("/app/hello", {}, JSON.stringify({ 'name': name }));
        }

        function showGreeting(message) {
            var response = document.getElementById('response');
            var p = document.createElement('p');
            p.style.wordWrap = 'break-word';
            p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));
            response.appendChild(p);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<noscript><h2 style="color: #ff0000">Seems your browser doesn't support Javascript! Websocket relies on Javascript being enabled. Please enable
    Javascript and reload this page!</h2></noscript>
<div>
    <div>
        <button id="connect" onclick="connect();">Connect</button>
        <button id="disconnect" disabled="disabled" onclick="disconnect();">Disconnect</button>
    </div>
    <div id="conversationDiv">
        <label>What is your name?</label><input type="text" id="name" />
        <button id="sendName" onclick="sendName();">Send</button>
        <p id="response"></p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**when I run it,an error occurred in browser console.**

```
Opening Web Socket... stomp.js:145
GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/hello/info 404 (Not Found)            sockjs.min.js:27
Whoops! Lost connection to undefined                                stomp.js:145
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in where you create the socket.

you should specify the contextRoot of your project

`var socket = new SockJS('{contextRoot}/hello');`